# How can I get an XML attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

Given this XML, how can I retrive the HEX color?

```
<group>
    <span style="color:#DF0000; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold">Webmaster</span>
</group>
```

I need to retrieve everything inside of the style. Then I can use the String.Substring method with .IndexOf() to retrieve the color for my use.

Thank you for the help.

Incase anyone is curious this is what I ended up with:

```
XElement str = doc.XPathSelectElement("/ipb/profile/group");                
                string color = str.Element("span").Attribute("style").Value;

                color = color.Substring(color.IndexOf('#'), 7);
                return color;
```

Comment: Can you add an ID to the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ-to-XML:

```
var elem = XElement.Parse(str);
var attr = elem.Element("span").Attribute("style").Value;
```

Note that if your HTML is not completely well-formed, you should consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: Great help as usual Slaks. I'll accept this answer when the timer finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the rest of your document looks like, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

```
    var node = xdoc.Descendants("group").Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault();

    string style = node.Attribute("style").Value;

    string[] styleElements = style.Split(';');

    var colorElements = from x in styleElements
                       where x.StartsWith("color", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                       select x;

    string colorElement = (string)colorElements.FirstOrDefault();
```